# 'Click to hide' button not working

Tags: bug, status-completed

When I click the 'Click to hide' button of the upper banner telling me to join, nothing happens.

[image]

It also it gives me the following error on the dev tools console:

```
full-anon.en.js?v=37d414698c5e:4
Uncaught TypeError: u.split is not a function
    at Object.t [as dismiss] (full-anon.en.js?v=37d414698c5e:4)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (one-finger-per-fret-is-it-worth-following-this-rule:464)
    at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I see it, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed in production now. Thanks for the report!